# station running roscore cannot listen to rostopics from other stations

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have an issue communicating with rostopics and are looking for a work-around (or at least explanation of the issue).

Suppose station A is running roscore and station B has mapped its ros master uri to station A.  Both station A and station B can see the full list of rostopics.  If station B publishes a topic, station A can subscribe to it, but it never receives any messages (for instance 'rostopic echo <topic_name>' never has output).  If station A subscribes to it, 'rostopic info' will show station A as a subscriber and station B as a publisher.

However, station A can publish messages to itself and can also receive service requests from station B.

Do you know why station A cannot receive messages from station B?  Does this seem like a network issue or is this an inherent/intended ROS feature?

In response to mwise_wg, setting the ROS_IP of station A to itself didn't change the behavior. Same with setting ROS_HOSTNAME on station A to it's own name. roswtf returns "ERROR Could not contact the following nodes: * /rostopic_3179_1..." and "ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10502/station-running-roscore-cannot-listen-to-rostopics-from-other-stations/) by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-07-06**:
Anything peculiar in each node's respective log for roscpp debug messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try

```
roswtf
```

It sounds like you need to set the ROS_HOSTNAME/ROS_IP on station A.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-07-07**:
Thanks, it worked when we set the ROS_IP to its respective station's IP adress

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-06**:
Both machines need to have set ROS_IP. Alternately both must be able to ping the others hostname (not only ip).

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-07-06**:
Setting the ROS_IP of station A to itself didn't change the behavior.  Same with setting ROS_HOSTNAME on station A to it's own name.  roswtf returns "ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:

- /rostopic_3179_1..." and "ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So we finally got it to work.
We set the ROS_MASTER_URI on stations B and C to station A and had the ROS_HOSTNAME/ROS_IP to its respective stations..
once we changed that, station A was able to listen and receive messages from other stations.

---

Originally posted by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) with karma: 207 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-03-25**:
So if i understood, on slave machines you set ROS_HOST as their IP adress and ROS_MASTER_URI as the URI of the Master machine. On the master machine you set ROS_HOST and ROS_MASTER_URI as master 's IP/URI. Still not working for me but I think it's because of some firewall. The thing is ,both machines can ping with each other